# Iphone 5 and Iphone 4 screen issue

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios5, ios6, screen-orientation

I'm creating an app using xcode 4.5 that is meant to support only the 3.5 inch retina display. Thus, in the attributes inspector for the view controller I have set the size to be 3.5 inches. However, I'm testing my app on a iphone 5 and the app auto-resizes to fit the whole screen. Do you know why this is happening? How can i make the app remain in 3.5 inches of size even when viewed off of a iphone 5?

Thanks

Comment: Why in the world would you want to do this? If I understand you correctly, you want to **explicitly not support** the iPhone 5?!

Comment: the reason for this is I am a high schooler and I don't want to get into making it support iphone 5 because I would have to learn auto resizing or I would have to draw multiple images for my background image.

Comment: Just remove the splash screen as per answer below and you should be fine.

Comment: Actually, i opened a new project and it works in that, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you remove the default 568h@2x icon from your project the app will run the way you want.  On the iPhone 5, you will get black bars on top and bottom to show what it would look like on the 4.  Hope this helps.

Comment: is this just the designated app icon in the target file?

Comment: because i never inserted an icon

Comment: It should be located in the left most pane of xcode.  Just below the project.

Comment: Clean and build.  Then try running your app again.

Comment: Actually, i opened a new project and it works in that, thanks!

Comment: Glad to help.  Good luck in class.  I teach physics and that's right down the hall from our computer science dept.  I always stop by to see what they are up to.  Have fun.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is - you can't do that :) But you can download ios5 simulator and set it's `device` property to 3.5 screen device

Comment: why can't you? What about the apps on the appstore that leave a black border on the top and bottom of the iphone, that's what I want to do.

Comment: oh, if thats enough that its surely possible, you should remove "default" image for iphone 5 (remove all if in doubt :)